# How to set new name after ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

I receive list of feeds from servlets like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${feedList}" var="feed">
    <tr>
        <td><input readonly="readonly" id="feedId"
            value="<c:out value="${feed.id}" />" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${feed.name}" /></td>
        <td><a
            href="FeedController?action=delete&id=<c:out value="${feed.id}"/>">Delete</a>
        </td>
        <td><a
            href="FeedItemController?action=feedItemListAsc&id=<c:out value="${feed.id}"/>">View</a></td>
        <td><button onclick="openEditDialog(${feed.id})" name="modal">Edit</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Edit open modal window that renames name with servlets:

```
$('#renameFeed').click(
        function() {
            var name = $('#feedName').val();
            var id = $('#feedId').val();
            var action = 'edit';

            var data = "feedName=" + name + "&id=" + id
                    + "&action=" + action;

            $.ajax({
                type : "Get",
                url : "FeedController",
                data : data,
            });
             $('#mask, .window').hide();
        });
```

After that new name for current record updated in database with servlets and all I want is to update it on page. Name remains the same until you refresh the page, how to display it after servlets change it in database on success without refreshing page?
Help me with syntax or example please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "Get",
    url : "FeedController",
    data : data,
  })
  .done(function() {
    // success (Here set new name)
  })
  .fail(function() {
    // error
  })
  .always(function() {
    // complete
  });
```

Learn more: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

**EDIT:**

You may want to add an `id` attribute to:

```
<td><c:out value="${feed.name}" /></td>
```

Like:

```
<td id="feed-name"><c:out value="${feed.name}" /></td>
```

And then:

```
$('#renameFeed').click(
    function() {
        var name = $('#feedName').val();
        var id = $('#feedId').val();
        var action = 'edit';

        var data = "feedName=" + name + "&id=" + id
                + "&action=" + action;

        $.ajax({
            type : "Get",
            url : "FeedController",
            data : data,
        }).done(function() {
            $('#feed-name').text(name);
        });

        $('#mask, .window').hide();
    });
```

**EDIT2:**

In loop:

```
<td id="feed-name${feed.id}"><c:out value="${feed.name}" /></td>
```

or

```
<td id="feed-name<c:out value="${feed.id}" />"><c:out value="${feed.name}" /></td>
```

(I don't know the sintaxis)

JS:

```
$('#feed-name' + id).text(name);
```

Comment: Ok,but what is the syntax to change it in jsp page with done function?

Comment: It works, but  $('#feed-name').text(name); changes the first name in jsp loop all the time.How to change it regarding on feedId?